# ACF bonding with vias on the pads

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I plan to use ACF bonding (hot-bar) to connect a display panel to a simple FR4 PCB.
As the circuit is very small and space optimized, I've positioned vias on some of the pads. If I would do use re-flow to connect the connector to the pads I would need to plug the vias with epoxy so solder won't run to the other side.

I would like **not** to epoxy fill the vias as this raises the cost of the PCB.

Will having non-plugged vias on the pads be a problem when doing ACF bonding?

Comment: Yes, for the same reasons as reflow.

Comment: I think if their process is good with microvias, there should be no issue.

Comment: Vias are not microvias but are still small, 0.2mm (didn't want to do microvias to avoid HDI manufacturing)